# Amazon Fulfilment plugins

Tags: magento-1.9, amazon-web-services, m2e

I have a client who has added al their products to Amazon. We brought them all down to Magento via one plugin and I have after some custom code and a CSV gotten all their attributes into Magento so we have a copy of the Amazon site on Magento.

I'm having a world of hurt trying to get any form of Amazon fulfillment working through magento though. I've tried the plugin by WebTex which gives no logs, no feedback, has no documentation and is just not helping. It has set all my products quantity to 0 after I assume not being bale to connect, find the products ro get the quantity.

I installed M2EPro and have tried to get this working but when I go to Manage listings and 3'rd party listings I get a error no the page. I assume I need to make a 3'rd party listings to bring down the Amazon quantities (The Amazon side is now taking ales so has updated quantities.)

I've looked at some other plugins but they all seem to have just as useless documentation, no instructions and I can't see them working.

I've picked this project up off another developer and am now way past the deadline so even though I know this isn't a usual Stack exchange question I'll ask anyway.

How at this point in time can I get quantities of products synchronizing from Amazon to Magento, use Amazon fulfillment and update Amazon when Magento makes sales? I'm 3 plugins down and at my wits end.

Answer (score 2):

M2E Pro is about to release a new M2E Pro Amazon next month (it is currently being tested) so you may want to wait till then. Otherwise send M2E pro support (via ticket system) question and someone will look into your problem.